# Lower led bulb intensity with resistor

Tags: led, resistors, led-driver

I am building a light bulb with an integrated neodymium magnet for an art piece. I have successfully integrated the magnet into a LED bulb model that suited my needs so it works but now I want to lower the brightness and it does not support dimming.

I have therefor decided to try to lower the brightness with a resistor but I don't want to break it so I want to ask about **the best place to position it** and **what strength/type of resistor to use** for it to not overheat or otherwise damage the circuit.

I tried doing this with an earlier model of the same kind and it worked but the next morning when I switched it back on it burnt out a LED diode. That time I put a 10K Ohm (or 1M Ohm resistor.. one of them gave me a good dampening of the light) between the LED circuit and the power going in (the gray cable marked B in the image). I am not sure if this was because I accidentally short circuited it or if current had been building up over the night and then it released it all at once.

So I would like to ask for some advice on the questions marked in bold above (placement and recommended resistor) or perhaps you will get back to me telling me not to do it that way, any valuable input is welcome. Below is an image of the finished bulb and the LED driver inside.

All help or advice is greatly appreciated, many thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: +1 for good job with the photo montage. What will the magnet do?

Comment: Add a circuit digram and don't forget to label all the components R1, C1 etc so we can advise better. Also how are you powering this?

Comment: Why not use an led with the brightness that you want?

Comment: @oldsea .What is the function of the magnet ?

Comment: @warren A circuit diagram would have been good, I agree, but I don't have experience in drawing them and I figured this circuit was simple enough that someone would understand it without. Hope that is ok. Will remember to label as recommended in the future. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Jason_Han That would have been the easiest option I agree but I found this one and it was well suited for incorporating the magnet.

Comment: @Autistic It keeps a knife balanced on a wine glass (http://victornyberg.com/img/CODA_Knife_on_Wine_Glass_Victor_Nyberg_2013.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

Your big metal film cap is is the main part that sets up led current and hence brightness . If you increase the series resistor value you will waste power to dim the lamp                .Halving C will halve the led current                        Try some lower values to get your desired level of brightness .Remember that this cap is a mains part and should be safety rated like X2 .If you do not have an assortment of caps on hand you can use your existing caps in series to ascertain your desired value for purchasing .

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will consider replacing the film cap as you suggested but I am inclined to take an easier route since power consumption is not an issue. 
If I decide to insert a resistor into the circuit, does it matter where I place it? And is there anything I need to consider regarding strength of the resistor in relation to where I place it? Thank you

Comment: Sorry to bump this with you, your answer is more than valid but it doesn't answer my primary question: Is inserting a resistor into the circuit an ok way to solve the issue?